# Managing My Database Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I am looking for some kind of library which does CRUD easily using PHP and MYSQL.
My goal is to make some app in flash AS3.0 , where i will be receiving some data from user and storing in data base , and perform CRUD opertaions. I dont want to be so much involved in writing php and sl query.
My scenario is:
Data types : [ like user_profile data, etc]
add under data types 1 to many fields with various types..
Database tables and realtions etc should be done by my DREAM library, then user when select a Dtat Type, he is presented with related fields to fill up data.

I will be using Flash AS3.0 ( Builder or IDE ) to perform. If only I can find some php library  I think AMFPHP can connect flash with php

Comment: Do yourself and the rest of a world a favor by learning how to properly design databases. People who don't know the first thing about third normal form have no right designing databases. Writing a PHP script that uses PDO and AMFPHP isn't very complicated, and is probably something else you should learn as well.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably spend more time trying to find exactly what your looking for than if you just created it yourself.

Comment: Actually I am not so good at MYSQL and database ,and it would take s much time too complete my work :(
May be i can create data type like this
obj.createType('Name');
obj.addField('Name','field_name','Type:Text');

then simply add data like
obj.getDataType('Name').add(['text for 1st field']);

Comment: You'll have to have a basic understanding of PHP and MySQL to implement a script. Creating a database and simple script is fairly easy and there a TON of tutorials on the internet. You'll probably have to modify the script to get it to do exactly what you want, so you should just take a couple of hours to understand the basics.

Comment: I know the basis and also have done simple work , but this thing seems complex , because more there will be more data types and different fields under every data type , Fields can be separted tables with linked dataTypes or a dataType table can have columns for field, this all seems complex and i have no such deep knowledge of things , i work in AS3.0 mostly :(

Comment: Then you'll need to hire someone. You're not going to find a solution that is going to work right out of the box

Comment: well is option is always there :)
i found some libs on the net named Database manager but those two were like myPHPadmin... anyhow hope this forum leads me to something.thnx

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://codeigniter.com/ - its a php mvc framework that lets you build php apps, websites etc.. very fast, because it has methods and functions already built in for the most common tasks like managing databases for example.

It has lots of tuts on http://net.tutsplus.com and one especially for you http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-5-crud/ , good luck!